# How to randomly color a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, random

I have a UILabel in a CustomCell and I would like to paint this label with a different color each time it is added to the table view.

```
let myBlue = UIColor(red: 62.0/255, green: 174.0/255, blue: 206.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
let myGreen = UIColor(red: 110.0/255, green: 186.0/255, blue: 64.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
let myRed = UIColor(red: 247.0/255, green: 118.0/255, blue: 113.0/255, alpha: 1.0)
let myYellow = UIColor(red: 255.0/255, green: 190.0/255, blue: 106.0/255, alpha: 1.0)

myLabel.backgroundColor = random(myBlue, myRed, myGreen, myYellow)
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: `myLabel.backgroundColor = [myBlue, myRed, myGreen, myYellow][Int(arc4random_uniform(4))]`  or  `[myBlue, myRed, myGreen, myYellow][arc4random_uniform(4).hashValue]`

Comment: if you want a method `func randomColor(colors: UIColor...) -> UIColor {
    return colors[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count)))]
}
`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myLabel.backgroundColor = random([myBlue, myRed, myGreen, myYellow])

 func random(colors: [UIColor]) -> UIColor {
         return colors[Int(arc4random_uniform(colors.count))]

 }
```

Comment: You could use variadic arguments to accomplish exactly the syntax OP asked

Comment: I had to change the return value to `return colors[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myColors.count)))]` as @LeoDabus suggested. Here is how I did it. Thanks `let myColors = [myRed, myBlue, myGreen, myYellow]`  `func random(colors: [UIColor]) -> UIColor {
            return colors[Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(myColors.count)))]
            
        }` `myLabel.backgroundColor = random(myColors)`